# Unable to use bonobo with teamcity

Tags: git, azure-web-app-service, teamcity-8.0, bonobo

I set up a bonobo server for storing our central git repos. This server is only available via http, not ssh.

In teamcity I added my VCS Root :

- Type: Git
- Fetch URL : https://myserver/myrepo.git
- Default branch : master
- Auth method : password
- Username : my user name
- Password : my password
- Path to git "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"

If I hit "test connection" I have a success.

On my build configuration I select my VCS with checkout mode "Automaticly on agent", I have to use this so i can make a push to the azure web app git deployment.

I set "git config --global credential.helper cache" on the teamcity agent server so it stores the credentials.

When I run my build configuration, the build is sutck like this

```
[12:06:11]Checking for changes
[12:06:11]Publishing internal artifacts
[12:06:11]Clearing temporary directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\temp\buildTmp
[12:06:11]Checkout directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\2eb5ccde57e744c6
[12:06:11]Updating sources: agent side checkout (running for 9s)
[12:06:11]Using vcs information from server. Reason: no revision information for buildtype SecureImmo and checkout directory D:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\2eb5ccde57e744c6 on agent
[12:06:11]Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Checkout directory was cleaned up with errors
[12:06:11]Cleaning D:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\2eb5ccde57e744c6
[12:06:11]Failed to delete empty directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\2eb5ccde57e744c6
[12:06:11]VCS Root: Bonobo (running for 9s)
[12:06:11]revision: e76753d88051cb2d3372714d4295c11513c208b8
[12:06:11]Cleaning D:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\2eb5ccde57e744c6
[12:06:11]Failed to delete empty directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\2eb5ccde57e744c6
[12:06:11]The .git directory is missing in 'D:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\2eb5ccde57e744c6'. Running 'git init'...
[12:06:12]Commit 'e76753d88051cb2d3372714d4295c11513c208b8' is not found in repository. Running 'git fetch'...
```

If i don't set automaticly on agent then I cannot push my project to azure web app's git.

Comment: Why do you say that the server is only accessible by "http not ssl", and then have an https:// URL in your VCS root configuration?

Comment: I meant "ssh", my bad.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion about http/https, but I'll assume  that's just a type in the question.

Your first step should be to make sure you can do a Git clone successfully ON YOUR AGENT MACHINE not your TC server, and then make sure you've put the same details into the VCS root config as you used to do the Git Clone.